# Android Tablerow unwanted row space

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Layout which consists of a RelativeLayout, with a TableLayout holding 15 rows. Basically this is supposed to be a board game.
Each row has 15 RelativeLayout with a ImageView inside each of them.
The three first ImageViews match up evenly, but from the fourth one the ImageViews get a bit smaller height, leaving a small white border / line between the rows.
I have no Idea how to fix this, can anyone help?

As you can see from the image below, the three first squares are in full height, whilst the rest have a line underneath them.

[image]

Here is a small part of the code, all the rows are exactly the same so no need to paste all 15:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableLayout 
    android:id="@+id/board"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <!-- 15 rows like this -->
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:padding="0dip">
    <!-- 15 relativeLayouts per Row -->
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/boardTile_15_1"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <!-- One ImageView per RelativeLayout -->
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:padding="0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/tile"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true">
    </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- End one RelativeLayout -->
    </TableRow>
    <!-- End one tableRow -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without testing, but a useful trick to 'debug' complex views like this, is adding background color to relevant subviews (i.e. `RelativeLayouts` containing your `ImageViews`), just to check who contains that padding.

You may also simplify as much as you can, for instance, you probably wouldn't need to wrap the `ImageViews` inside `RelativeLayouts`.

That said, my guess is that `ImageViews` need their `scaleType` attribute to be set, they'd look something like.-

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/tile"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

There's no need to set padding/margin, as they're 0 by default, and remember that `fill_parent` is deprecated from API level 8.

Comment: And how about removing that space and limiting grid size to content(wrapping) ?